# How to find the area of regular dodecagon in this question of Geometry Math Competition Singapore

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I was doing practice papers when I saw this question. It is like this: 
**"Find the area of regular dodecagon - $2\cdot$ area of regular hexagon. All sides (both polygons) are $7$ cm long".** Without knowing the formula for dodecagons, is there any other way to solve this conundrum?
Note: This is not the correct phrasing
Also, I'm 12, so I don't understand much. All I know is that the answer requires some moving of polygons.
In addition, this question is from a past year paper, which means it came out before! The answer cannot be too hard...

Comment: Its not very clear. Whose polygon has side 7 cm? Do we have to find the area of the dodecagon or what?

Comment: The area of regular dodecagon is not double of that of a hexagon.

Comment: The formulas can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagon#Regular_dodecagon), you have the side, plug it and get the area. But I don't see the relation to the hexagon?

Comment: That's the problem. I can't tell the relation either... Also, I never said the answer had to be 0. (Your 2nd comment hints that)

Comment: 0? No, I never hinted that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Draw hexagon.
Step 2: Draw lines joining opposite vertices of the hexagon. 
Step 3: Draw one square from each of the sides, outwards of the hexagon.
Step 4: Join the free edges of each square.

Notice that we have a figure of 12 equilateral triangles and 6 squares. Areawise, 6 triangles add up to a hexagon. The entire figure is off a dodecahedron. Thus, the required area is that of 6 squares = 294 cm^2.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful! You're on your way!

Comment: That's one clever solution. I, for one, would've taken the ugly trigonometric path instead. :P

Answer (score 0):

Connect all vertices to centroid of $n-$gon. It will divide $360^\circ$ into $n$ equal parts. You can now find each part of angle and thus all angles in each (congruent) triangle formed.

Note that each triangle formed in hexagon is equilateral. You can find its area by making a perpendicular bisector and using congruent triangles. When you have found area of one triangle, multiply by $6$ for whole hexagon.

Wait till I edit to find area of dodecagon without trigonometry... or just read trigonometry at Wikipedia... its really simple.

Comment: I'm actually 11. I haven't understood how to do trigonometry. I remember glimpsing (I was too stubborn in doing the problem by myself) at an answer which the polygons have to be shaped into something...

Comment: @jonnytan999 Editing